# operator cannot be applied to Integer

Tags: java

I am writing an abstract class and a class extends it.

```
public abstract class stream<T>{
  public abstract T data();
}
```

Above is the abstract class.

```
public class IntegerStream<Integer> extends stream{
  private Integer InitialV;

  public IntegerStream(Integer InitialV){
    this.InitialV = InitialV;
  }

  public Integer next(){
   InitialV = InitialV + 1;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer data() {
    return InitialV;
  }

}
```

the result should be like 
when create

```
stream = new IntegerStream(10);

    > stream.next()
    10
    > stream.next()
    11
    > stream.next()
    12
```

but here is the error when I tried to compile it:

```
operator + cannot be applied to Integer,int
```

Anyone can help me..

Comment: The problem is with type `Integer` use `T`.

Comment: return statement is missing in `public Integer next()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this declaration

```
public class IntegerStream<Integer> extends stream{
```

the name `Integer` between `<>` is declaring a type variable named `Integer`, it isn't referring to the type `java.lang.Integer`.

It's also an unbounded type, so any type can be used. As such, the operator `+` cannot be applied to operands of that type.

What you probably wanted is

```
public class IntegerStream extends stream<Integer> {
```

so that you bind `Integer` (`java.lang.Integer`) as the type argument for the generic `stream` class (make it uppercase `Stream`).